# Underline the first letter of an anchor tag in a list on hover using jQuery or CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-lists

I am trying to underline the first letter of a link on hover for each item in a list. I have tried the CSS first_letter selector, but all that does is underlines the first letter of the first item.

Here is the list:

```
<ul class="list">
   <li><a class="underline" href="Lingua%20Franca.html">Lingua Franca</a></li>
   <li><a class="underline" href="Within%20Within.html">Within Within</a></li>
   <li><a class="underline" href="Kind%20Pockets.html">Kind Pockets</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have tried this and many variations of it:

```
a.underline:hover:first-letter{
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do it with jQuery, this will work as long as the contents of the anchor aren't complex

http://jsfiddle.net/rEcx7/1/

```
$(function(){
    $("#stuff li a").hover(function(){
        var thisHtml=$(this).html();

        $(this).html("<span style='text-decoration: underline;'>"+thisHtml.substring(0,1)+"</span>"+thisHtml.substring(1));
    },function(){
       $(this).find("span").contents().unwrap();
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Elegant solution. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 7):

Well, `::first-letter` is a pseudo-element, not a pseudo-class, so it requires two colons:

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#first-letter

However, I started [playing around in JSFiddle in Chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/nFQfK/) and it seems like there are issues using them together. Even before factoring in anchor element and its default underline, I tried this with vanilla `LI`s (no links in them):

```
li::first-letter:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;   
}
```

and

```
li::first-letter:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;   
}
```

and neither of them worked, although

```
li::first-letter {
 text-decoration: underline;   
}
```

does work.

You might just have to wrap those first letters in a span with a custom class instead of relying on `::first-letter`.

Comment: Double colon is a Good point as well as including code from the fiddle.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a pure CSS solution that works in webkit browsers, such as Chrome and Safari.

http://jsfiddle.net/mqchen/cQCSp/

After a bit of trying I finally got a pure CSS solution that also works in Firefox 4:

http://jsfiddle.net/mqchen/cQCSp/3/

The CSS:

```
.list a.underline {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.list li .underline:first-letter {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.list li:not(:hover) .underline:first-letter {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: This works in most cases. You are a CSS ninja. I went with the jQuery, but thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go (without touching html part):

http://jsfiddle.net/sLdWL/

Comment: This solution also works perfectly. I will vote this up when I have the ability. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you mean:

```
<ul class="list">
    <li><a class="underline" href="Lingua%20Franca.html"><span class="first">L</span>ingua Franca</a></li>
    <li><a class="underline" href="Within%20Within.html"><span class="first">W</span>ithin Within</a></li>
    <li><a class="underline" href="Kind%20Pockets.html"><span class="first">K</span>ind Pockets</a></li>
</ul>

a.underline {
    text-decoration:none;   
}
a.underline:hover .first {
    text-decoration:underline;   
}
```

Comment: Proulx That was the first way I won, but adding the span to each item in a long list is tedious. This works well though. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

See these:

First letter underlined, no hover:
http://jsfiddle.net/WmBYQ/1/

First letter underlined, hover underlines whole item:
http://jsfiddle.net/WmBYQ/2/

It seems like `:first-letter` selector is well accepted for `p` tags. I chose to embrace your `li` items with a paragraph, and then change the css to fit this.